# Lego Mindstorms NXT 2.0 brick is not working

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, instructions, repair

Recently, I tried to get my old NXT 2.0 brick fixed.
Everything seemed to point to the clicking brick problem, but it turns out not to be the only thing, the brick was also getting hot. After disassembling it, I found that the "q27" transistor was burning up.

There is "11 2x" written on the part, but it didn't point me to anything on the internet and I couldn't find any schematic for NXT 2.0 on the web. Any ideas how to identify the part?

Or maybe anyone saw the schematic for NXT 2.0?
Would writing an email to Lego give me anything?

Comment: writing to lego will not help as they are no longer working on the NXT, alternatively you can buy a replacement from third-party seller like eBay.

Comment: I do not think this is something we can solve, we are not expert technicians using weird electric thingies to spot other weird electric thingies. I think you should probably buy a replacement.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Even though the subject matter of this site is not electronics, it is a valid LEGO question, and I think the tone of your comment is not very welcoming to the OP, who is asking for our help.

Comment: It's ok. The thing I was after the most is the schematic. If it isn't anywhere, I'm out of luck and will reverse engineer the power regulator inside. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: If the getting the schematic is the main goal then perhaps we should change the title of the question.

Comment: @mindstormsboi this is wrong. I recently contacted Lego about a dead screen and they gave me a replacement brick.

Comment: HI bit old now but did you find the problem as i have the same issue Q26 and Q27 very hot, and have the brick click. TP87 at 8.7v OK, and TP90 at 5v again ok.
Brick does not appear on USB.

Answer (score 1):

The electrial schematic for the NXT is available in the LEGO "NXT Hardware Developer Kit". This can be found on the [official LEGO MINDSTORMS download page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads) near the bottom of the page in the *Advanced Users – Developer Kits* section.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the main chip is dead. But if you don't have decent soldering gear then you might as well just get a new brick.

Answer (score 0):

It will never hurt to contact Lego support. Customer support is busy right now so at worst you will get a no in a few days. I have had great experience with Lego support, sending me replacement pieces and replacing my NXT brick with a dead screen (common problem). You may need to provide some proof of purchase (for the NXT brick I wasn't, and I don't remember for the pieces).